# How to randomize numbers within strings where the incoming format is not known?

Tags: python, string, machine-learning, random, format

For a NLP project i need to generate **randomized number strings** for training purpose, based on training examples. Numbers come as strings (from OCR). Let me restrict the problem statement here to percentage values, where so far observed formats include the following formats or any meaningful combination of the pointed-out format features:

```
'60'       # no percentage sign, precision 0, no other characters
'60.00'    # no percentage sign, precision 2, dot for digit separation
'60,000'   # no percentage sign, precision 3, comma for digit separation
'60.0000'  # no percentage sign, precision 4, dot for digit separation
'60.00%'   # same as above, with percentage sign
'60.00 %'  # same as above, with whitespace
'100%'     # three digits, zero precision, percentage sign
'5'        # single digit
'% 60'     # percentage sign in front of the number, whitespace
```

my goal is to randomize the number while **preserving** the per-character-format (exception: due to different amount in digits when a 5.6 could be randomized to 18.7 or 100.0 and vice versa). The percentage number value should lie between 0 and 100. A few examples how i need it:

```
input  = '5'  # integer-like digit
output = [  '7', 
           '18', 
          '100'] 

input  =  '100.00 %' # 2-precision float with whitespace & percentage sign
output = [  '5.38 %', 
           '38.05 %', 
          '100.00 %']  

inpput =  '% 60,000' # percentage sign, whitespace, 4-precision float, comma separator
output = ['% 5,5348', 
          '% 48,7849', 
          '% 100,0000']
```

How could I do this? The solution can be both **conceptual** or a **code example**.
The solution needs to reflect possible formats that may appear in the real data

The best i know so far is to brute-force handwrite if-clauses for every format variation i can come up with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following seems to work for the example inputs you provided. We're only interested in finding the leading integer digits and a potential separator followed by more digits. We don't actually need to look for any whitespace or percentage signs, since we're only interested in replacing the digits in any given match, anyway. Let me know if I missed something:

```
import re

pattern = "\\d{1,3}((?P<separator>[,.])(?P<floating>\\d+))?"

strings = (
    "60",
    "60.00",
    "60,000",
    "60.0000",
    "60.00%",
    "60.00 %",
    "100%",
    "5",
    "% 60",
    "% 60,000"
)

def randomize(match):
    from random import uniform

    integer, floating = divmod(uniform(0, 100), 1)

    def get_chars():
        yield str(int(integer))
        if match.group("separator") is not None:
            yield match.group("separator")
            precision = len(match.group("floating"))
            yield f"{{:.{precision}f}}".format(floating)[2:]
    return "".join(get_chars())
        
    

for string in strings:
    print(re.sub(pattern, randomize, string))
```

Output:

```
29
95.08
51,507
9.1783
0.80%
6.56 %
16%
22
% 27
% 93,174
>>>
```

Comment: Fan-dam-tastic! This is so beautiful and as general as the problem statement allows. Thanks!

Comment: @Dr-Nuke Haha, you're welcome. Glad you think it's beautiful, I think it could be prettier, actually. It does make some assumptions, like that the input will always contain leading digits, or that if a separator is present, that there will necessarily be trailing digits after it.

Comment: I actually do not understand a part of it: that is, you define a function with one argument randomize(match), but call it without argument. could you provide or link some explanation? Thanks!

Comment: @Dr-Nuke I'm not actually "calling" it, I'm just passing the function object as a parameter. Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) for `re.sub`. The second argument can either be a string with which to replace any match, or, in our case, it can be a callable object (function, lambda, etc), which takes the current match as a parameter. All you do is pass the function object as a parameter to `re.sub`, and it will pass the match object to the passed callable, whenever a match is found.

Answer (score 0):

The following func can be called to generate random numbers required in your case. You can modify it further to suit it best to your case.

```
import numpy as np
def random_gen():
    precison = np.random.randint(0,6)
    val = np.random.uniform(0, 100)
    val = round(val,int(precison))
    val = str(val)
    
    white_space = np.random.randint(0,3)
    rand_index = np.random.randint(0,len(val))
    val = val[0:rand_index] + ' '*white_space + val[rand_index:]
    
    if np.random.randint(0,2) > 0:
        if np.random.randint(0,2) > 0:
            val = val + "%"
        else:
            val = "%" + val
    return val

random_gen()
```